# How do I attach file in mail that sharepoint send when I invite/give access to user on sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In share point online 2013, When I add user and send an email invitation is checked, so it does send the user email invitation and URL of the site.

How do I send/attach file(word Document) as well when I give user access to the SharePoint site and share point send email to the user on their email address ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to reference a document which is publicly available. You can share a document in your SharePoint Online tenant via a guest link.

Just make sure your message doesn't exceed 255 characters.